# Read json data in d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

i created a stacked chart in d3.js. reading data from a file. Now I want to read from json. what changes i need to do in order to read from json.

```
    Below is code for the chart.

    d3.tsv("./StackedChart/stackeddata_dept1.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
    x_stacked.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.department; }));
    y0_stacked.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return 100; })]);

    svg1.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height_stacked + ")")
            .call(xAxis_stacked);

    svg1.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis axisLeft")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
            .call(yAxisLeft_stacked)
            .append("text")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", "-2em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .style("text-anchor", "end");

    bars = svg1.selectAll(".bar").data(data).enter();

    bars.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar1")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x_stacked(d.department); })
            .attr("width", x_stacked.rangeBand()/2)
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y0_stacked(d.positive); })
            .attr("height", function(d,i,j) { return height_stacked - y0_stacked(d.positive); });
});

function type(d) {
    d.positive = +d.positive;
    return d;
}
```

Data in file is :

department  positive    negative
Finance 63.5299997329712    36.9699997901917
HR  43.6424999237061    56.3575010299683
Production  43.1399993896484    57.0625009536743
Sales   65.1949987411499    34.8049998283386

Any help appreciated.
all i need to know is what changes in the code needs to be done in order to read from json.
as now the data would be in json , not in a file.
what are possible ways to read data in d3 instead of using file?

Answer (score 0):

You're currently reading from a tsv file using **d3.tsv()**.

In order to read a JSON file, your have to use the [d3.json()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json) method

Comment: d3.json() reads from a json file. but i require to read from an json object. also what are other possible ways to read from instead of file.